# UIButtons don't move

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

I am new in iOS development, and I have got a problem that I haven't solved for the last two days.
The problem is:
I have got one `ViewController`, that has a few `UIButtons` on the right edge of the View. They were made using Interface Builder.
There is an `UIView`, it stands on the left edge.
Buttons and `UIView` are visible at the begining.
Also, there is an `UIView` that stands on the right, and it is out of the visibility zone.
I need to have an animation as result of which, left View goes more left, out of visibility, buttons from the right edge goes to left edge and the right View goes to the center of View.
I made a code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.p.center = CGPointMake (self.p.center.x-260, self.p.center.y);
        self.dimensionButton.center = CGPointMake (self.dimensionButton.center.x-260, self.dimensionButton.center.y);
        self.speedButton.center = CGPointMake (self.speedButton.center.x-260, self.speedButton.center.y);
        self.temperatureButton.center = CGPointMake (self.temperatureButton.center.x-260, self.temperatureButton.center.y);
        self.volumeButton.center = CGPointMake (self.volumeButton.center.x-260, self.volumeButton.center.y);
        self.weightButton.center = CGPointMake (self.weightButton.center.x-260, self.weightButton.center.y);
        self.currencyButton.center = CGPointMake (self.currencyButton.center.x-260, self.currencyButton.center.y);
        self.calculationScreen.center = CGPointMake(self.calculationScreen.center.x-260, self.calculationScreen.center.y);

    }];
```

Buttons don't go to the left, but both of the Views do, and I don't know why.
I tried to remake animation like this:
not to move buttons and views to the left, but move self.view to the right.
But I had problem: buttons on the right view(`calculateScreen`) didn't work at all(there were not even animation of touch).

Comment: Are you certain all of the outlets are connected?  Consider NSLog(@"%@", self.buttonThatIsntMoving); before the animation.

Comment: All outlets are connected, moreover i had NSLog's before and after animations, and they say that, coordinates of buttons are right, and buttons should be on left edge, but they don't

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, you should do any animations by changing the constraints rather than setting centers.

Comment: Thank you for idea, now I am reading about auto layout, I'll write as soon as I'll try

Comment: Code looks okay.  Just need some debugging.  Reduce the animation to include just two views: one that moves properly and one that doesn't.  NSLog both views beforehand (that will log their frames).  Add a completion block to the animation which logs the views again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for your help.

In fact, the problem was in Auto Layout system. It was trying to save the distance between the right edge of `Button` and the right edge of `self.view`. That distance was equal 0, so buttons didn't want to move left. The problem was solved by removing the tick "Use autolayout" on the buttons property.

Comment: If you want to use auto layout, you can animate your constraints instead of the views' frames.

Answer (score 0):

Change their `transform` rather that changing their `center`. That's what it's meant for.